# Память и imageView Android

Tags: android

В процессе создания игры-квеста использую несколько `imageView`. Два из них полноразмерные - `HD`. Первый это фоновое изображение `1280х720`, второе прозрачная рамка, тоже `720p`. Изображения для фона меняются по клику на ключевые объекты, а рамка остается, и лишь иногда убирается. Рамка в `PNG` занимает 3.8кб, тогда как `JPG` фоны от 120 до 260кб.

Загружаю фон в `imageView` конструкцией

```
cam.setImageResource(R.drawable.cam1);
```

В итоге получается что на слабых телефонах приложение просто вылетало после перехода из меню в выбор эпизода, потому как там тоже 2 `HD` картинки.
Исправил ситуацию так:

```
<Application
android:largeHeap="true" />
```

Перестало вылетать, но теперь при просмотре занимаемой оперативной памяти ступор: проходит сплеш, меню, выбор эпизода, игровой экран - всего загружено 7 `HD` изображений в `ImageView`, а уже 100мб оперативки и дикие лаги! Тест на реальных телефонах.

Прошу помощи- как исправить такую утечку памяти не меняя кардинально концепцию игры. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А где у Вас лежат картинки? В какой папке?

Comment: @EugeneKuzmenko, в ресурсах, это очевидно.

Comment: Я могу предложить вам нарезать несколько наборов картинок разных размеров под разные экраны, тогда будет нормально работать.

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко, та не очень очевидно) Т.к. он мог положить их в mdpi, hdpi и т.д. Мог вообще положить в assets. Под каждое разрешение не обязательно нарезать, достаточно правильно указать изначальную папку ресурсов с необходимым разрешением.

Comment: Картинки лежат в drawable. Игра делается только под HD экраны

Comment: ребята, очень сильно поможете!!! прошу, подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с большими изображениями(массивами изображений) вам нужно использовать openGL, чтобы загружать ваши большие изображения в память видеокарты. Тогда не будет использоваться оперативная память и приложения не будут тупить.

Пример рендера и шейдер для вывода изображения(спрайта) в openGL можете взять тут:
https://github.com/Karavanych/glesImages

Либо использовать движок, например libgdx.
http://habrahabr.ru/post/143405/

Comment: буду двигаться в этом направлении. спасибо